# Read datetime from a file and add one second

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm reading a timestamp from a file and I'd like to copy the value to the START_DATE variable, and add 1 second to that value.

```
export START_DATE=`cat ${WINDOW_END_FILE}`
```

Timestamp format

```
2019-04-03-23.59.59
```

In the end, I'd like the date to be

```
2019-04-04-00.00.00
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date to epoch time, then add 1:

```
fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S' 
date -j -f %s $(( $(date -j -f "$fmt" 2019-04-03-23.59.59 +%s) + 1 )) +"$fmt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes, this isn't pretty, but fun:

If I understood, let's just say `START_DATE=2019-04-03-23.59.59`

```
# Pull Date section
date=$(echo $START_DATE | cut -d - -f 1-3)
# Pull Time section
time=$(echo $START_DATE | cut -d - -f 4 | sed 's/\./:/g')
# Use bash builtin date function for conversion
date -d "$cal $time + 1 second" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"
```

Output:

```
2019-04-04-00-00-00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '{
    gsub(/[^0-9]/," ")                          # change the format mktime friendly
    print strftime("%F-%H.%M.%S",mktime($0)+1)  # to epoch, add one, reformat back
}' file                                         # a timestamp from a file
2019-04-04-00.00.00                             # output this time
```

`mktime` turns datespec (`YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]`) to number of seconds since the system epoch. `strftime` formats the timestamp to given format.